# Probability mass function - find the second tallest boy in a room.

Tags: probability

A kindergarten class consists of $12$ boys and $4$ girls. The children are arranged from tallest to shortest. Assume that all $16!$ rankings are equally likely, and no two children are exactly the same height. Let the random variable $X$ be the rank of the second tallest boy. Assume that the tallest person in the class is rank $1$. Find the pmf $f(x)$.

I can see that the support $\mathcal{A}={2,3,4,5,6}$.

Comment: What work have you done and where are you getting stuck? What is the ranking that you are referring to in the problem? Ranked by height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the second tallest boy to have rank $r$, you'd need $r-2$ taller girls, and $1$ taller boy.  Choose these taller children, order them, and then choose the second tallest boy.

For instance, $P(X=4)=\frac{12\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot 6\cdot 11}{16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13}=\frac{99}{910}$

Comment: In the numerator of your probability, why do you multiply by $6$? I get that you're muliplying the choices for the tallest and second tallest boys ($12$ and $11$), and then you're choosing two out of the four girls, but where does the $6$ come in...?

Comment: Oh I think you explained this in your answer and I misread it... You need to order the children that are taller than the second tallest boy, so in your example you have $4-1=3$ positions available, and in those positions there are $3*2*1=6$ possibilities of ordering. I get it. Thanks!